# Find files in shell script using a conditional based on a substring

Tags: bash, shell, find, sh

I am writing a shell script to match different files together based on a shared identifier. This identifier is the date in the format: `MMDDYY`. For example, a file with the name `010518id.xml` would have been created January 5th, 2018. I need it to only find files that were created after 2013.

I have this line in the shell script currently:

```
nfiles=$(find $SEARCH_DIR -name $fileName'*.xml' -type f)
```

I am thinking of getting the year by calling `fileYear = ${fileName:3:2}`, then using `if[ ${#fileYear} -gt 13 ]`, and nesting, in that statement, one that checks if the count of nfiles is above a certain amount.

Is this the best way to do this? There is probably some way of doing this in one or two commands, but this is the first shell script I have had to write.

Comment: `find -name '????1[3-9]*.xml'`???

Comment: Ah, I overlooked regex possibilities. Thank you.

Comment: it's called glob, not regex. you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

since you stated that:

> I need it to only find files that were created after 2013.

and 2013 lasted until Dec 31st, I will assume any file from Jan 1st 2014 until today, so:

test files:

```
$ ls -1 *.xml
010313id.xml
010518id.xml
011012id.xml
```

output:

```
$ find . -regextype egrep -regex .*[0-9]{4}1[4-9]id.*
./010518id.xml
```

Explanation:

> `-regextype egrep` : Defines egrep as regexp syntax to be understood
>
> `-regex` : declare that I will use regexp, which is:
>
> `.*` : any character zero or more times, followed by:
>
> `[0-9]{4}` : any digit exactly four times, followed by:
>
> `1` : the number one, followed by:
>
> `[4-9]` any digit between 4 and 9 (to simulate 2014 until today)
>
> `id` : to keep file name format